# Directiva con controller y parametro en Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, controller

Estoy usando Typescript 1.8 + angularjs v.1.5.8

Tengo una directiva que quiero llamar asi:

```
<div mi-directiva mi-parametro="ctrl.Objeto"> </div>
```

Mi directiva esta declarada asi:

```
export class miDirectiva implements ng.IDirective{ 
     restrict:'A';
     templateUrl = '/views/template.url';
     controller = 'miController';
     controllerAs = 'ctrl';
     bindToController = true;
     scope:{
              miParametro:'='
           }

     constructor(){}

     static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = () => new miDirectiva();
        return directive;
     }
}

var app=angular.module('App');
app.directive('miDirectiva',[miDirectiva.factory()]);
```

Mi controller esta declarado asi

```
export class miController{

  miParametro:any;

  constructor(scope:any){ 

     var x = scope.miParametro;//undefined
     var y = this.miParametro; //undefined

     //Como tengo acceso a miParametro?????
  }
}

var app=angular.module('App');
app.controller('miController',['$scope', miController]);
```

Hechos:

- miParametro es un objeto
- Segun lo que he leido, no necesito la funcion $link ni $compile, esto no es necesario ya que estoy declarando que `bindToController=true` y que miParametro ya deberia estar alli disponible en el controller
- Si recibo el objeto `$attrs` en el controller si puedo obtener el objeto mediante `$scope.$eval($attrs.miParametro)` pero algo me dice que esto no se hace asi

**Como tengo acceso a miParametro?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya quedo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33322500/3596441

Movi la definicion del scope a `bindToController` y funcionó, `miParametero` ya este disponible en `miController`

```
export class miDirectiva implements ng.IDirective{ 
     restrict = 'A';
     templateUrl = '/views/template.url';
     controller = 'miController';
     controllerAs = 'ctrl';
     bindToController = {
        miParametro: '='
     }
     scope = {}

     constructor(){}

     static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = () => new miDirectiva();
        return directive;
     }
}

var app=angular.module('App');
app.directive('miDirectiva',[miDirectiva.factory()]);
```